# How can i display chart from code behind in windows phone

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone

I create a chart in my windows phone app.this is my code XAML

```
<amq:SerialChart x:Name="line"  DataSource="{Binding results}" CategoryValueMemberPath="month"
 AxisForeground="White"
 PlotAreaBackground="Black"
 GridStroke="DarkGray"  >
                <amq:SerialChart.Graphs>
                    <amq:LineGraph Title="Sales" ValueMemberPath="actual" Brush="red" StrokeThickness="5" />
                </amq:SerialChart.Graphs>

            </amq:SerialChart>
```

How can i write this XAML  with c# (code behind only)

Answer (score 1):

> How can i write this XAML with c# (code behind only)

In general this is usually not a good idea.  But if you must, you would use something along these lines:

```
var chart = new SerialChart
{
    CategoryValueMemberPath = "month",
    AxisForeground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White),
    PlotAreaBackground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black),
    GridStroke = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.DarkGray)
};
chart.SetBinding(SerialChart.DataSourceProperty, new Binding("results"));

var lineGraph = new LineGraph
{
    Title = "Sales",
    ValueMemberPath = "actual",
    Brush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red),
    StrokeThickness = "5"
};
chart.Graphs.Add(lineGraph);
```

Then you would just need to add the chart to the page/container using for example `stackPanel.Children.Add(chart)`.

Comment: AxisForeground="White",
                 PlotAreaBackground="Black",
                  GridStroke="DarkGray"

error message "Can not implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.Windows.Media.Brush'"

Answer (score 0):

```
var chart = new SerialChart
{
    CategoryValueMemberPath = "month",
    AxisForeground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White),
    PlotAreaBackground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black),
    GridStroke = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.DarkGray)
};
chart.SetValue(SerialChart.DataSourceProperty, new Binding("results"));

var lineGraph = new LineGraph
{
    Title = "Sales",
    ValueMemberPath = "actual",
    Brush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red),
    StrokeThickness = 5
};
chart.Graphs.Add(lineGraph);
```